# How does the Dirichlet process work?

Tags: st.statistics, pr.probability

Hi, i'm looking to get into nonparametric bayesian techniques but I'm having problem understanding what's going on in the definition of the Dirichlet process or how it works. So what does P ~ DP(α*P<sub>0</sub>) mean?

What does a distribution P looks like? Is the samples being used, X<sub>i</sub> ~ P?

Comment: It might help if you let us know what definition you have in front of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a fan of Yee Whye Teh's tutorials, listed under "Short Courses" here:
http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~ywteh/teaching/teaching.html

You can also watch the video on videolectures if you want an explanation to accompany the slides.

Answer (score 2):

Are you taking about the Dirichlet-Poisson process? 
If yes then a nice introduction is in http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.3985 .

It is too long to put here (you have to read first about random partitions) but it gives some intuitions.

Answer (score 0):

We can go by the common definition posted [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process)

Comment: You should edit the question to include this link there instead of posting it in an answer.